# C++: How to correctly return a pointer to an object

Tags: c++

I have been stumbling over this problem for a while now.  I am trying to return a pointer to an object to I can say

```
MyObject* obj = Manager::Create(int i, int j);
```

How do I correctly allocate memory so there are no leaks? I thought I was supposed to call new to make the memory on the heap but I have recently been told otherwise.

Comment: Well, how does `Manager::Create` allocate the `MyObject`? Is there a `Manager::Destroy`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I thought I was supposed to call new to make the memory on the heap but I have recently been told otherwise.

Well... I think you're a bit confused.  Yes, you do call `new` to dynamically allocate memory.  However, there are common patterns (see; [RAII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Acquisition_Is_Initialization)) that are used to avoid it at all costs as it is an easy way to shoot yourself in the foot (read; write bugs).

At some point, *somethign* has to call `new` in order to dynamically allocate memory.  first though you need to ask yourself; does this need to be dynamically allocated?  If the answer is no, then declare it like so and move on.

```
void Foo() { 
    MyObject obj;  // automatic storage space, will be cleaned up when the scope is left
}
```

Next, why not store the pointer in a `std::unique_ptr` or something equivalent?  That will take care of management for you, again, you don't manage the memory;

```
// calls delete in the destructor
std::unique_ptr pointer( new MyObject() );
```

The BOOST library has an equivalent class (`unique_ptr` is C++11).

The point is that memory is being managed by the class via its constructor and destructor.  You allocate memory dynamically when you create the object and you deallocate it (i.e., call `delete`) in its destructor.  You simply stack allocate these in as tight a scope as possible and you don't have to worry about memory leaks.

I write C++ at work every day and I almost *never* call `new` or `delete`.  As a small example, let's examine this class, which is a trivial implementation of a scoped pointer (note; this is not a "correct" implementation and is overly trivial!  This problem is harder to solve than this, but I am using it solely as an example of managing the lifetime of a dynamically allocated object).

```
template<class T>
class ScopedPointer {
public:
    ScopedPointer(T* obj) {
        m_pointer = obj;
    }

    ~ScopedPointer() {
        delete m_pointer;
    }

    inline T* operator->() 
    { 
        return( m_pointer );
    }

    inline bool IsValid() const {
        return m_pointer != NULL;
    }

private: 
    T* m_pointer;
};
```

You may use this class as a wrapper around a pointer to dynamically allocated memory.  When it leaves its scope its destructor will be called and the memory will be cleaned up.  Again, this is not production quality code!  It is not correct in that it lacks several mechanisms that a real world class would need (copy/ownership semantics, a more advanced deallocater, etc.)

```
void Foo() {
    ScopedPointer<MyObject> ptr( new MyObject() );
    ptr->whatever();
}  // destructor is called, dynamic memory is freed
```

Answer (score 4):

> “I have been stumbling over this problem for a while now. I am trying to return a pointer to an object to I can say
>
> ```
>    MyObject* obj = Manager::Create(int i, int j);
> ```
>
> How do I correctly allocate memory so there are no leaks? I thought I was supposed to call new to make the memory on the heap but I have recently been told otherwise.”

Since you’re asking about how to allocate memory, and since that happens inside `Manager::Create`, the only reasonable interpretation I can see is that you’re the one writing the `Manager::Create` function.

So, first of all, *do you really need a factory*, and what, if anything, is the *“manager”* actually managing?

It is my impression that people coming from a Java background have a strong tendendcy to add needless dynamic allocation and factories and “managers” and singletons and envelope patterns and whatnot, that are generally ungood in C++.

Don’t.

For example, if your `obj` is only needed in a local scope, ***use automatic storage*** (stack based allocation and deallocation), which can be orders of magnitude more efficient than Java-like dynamic allocation:

```
    MyObject obj( i, j );
```

It this is applicable, then the question “How do I correctly allocate memory so there are no leaks” has a very simple answer in C++: ***just declare the variable***, as above.

This applies even if you have to return such an object from a function. Then just ***return by value*** (apparently copying the object). For example as with the `foo::reduce` function below,

```
#include <iostream>         // std::cout, std::endl
#include <string>           // std::string, std::to_string

namespace foo {
    using namespace std;

    class MyObject
    {
    private:
        string      description_;

    public:
        string description() const { return description_; }

        MyObject( int const x, int const y )
            : description_( "(" + to_string( x + 0LL ) + ", " + to_string( y + 0LL ) + ")" )
        {}
    };

    ostream& operator<<( ostream& stream, MyObject const& o )
    {
        return stream << o.description();
    }

    int gcd( int a, int b )
    {
        return (b == 0? a : gcd( b, a % b ));
    }

    MyObject reduce( int const a, int const b )
    {
        int const gcd_ab = gcd( a, b );
        return MyObject( a/gcd_ab, b/gcd_ab );
    }
}  // namespace foo

int main()
{
    using namespace foo;
    
    int const   a = 42;
    int const   b = 36;

    cout << MyObject( a, b ) << " -> " << reduce( a, b ) << endl;
}
```

Now let’s see how this concise, simple and efficient code can be made verbose, complex and inefficient by introducing needless dynamic allocation. I write “needless” because most of the traditional reasons for dynamic allocation have been obviated by the containers etc. of the standard C++ library and the facilities of the C++ language. For example, where previously you might have used pointers to avoid costly copying, and consequently getting into the question “i need to clean up, but was the object allocated on automatic storage or dynamically?“, with C++03 you could use smart pointers such as `boost::shared_ptr` to automate proper destruction regardless of the object’s origins, and with C++11 you can use move semantics to largely avoid the copying inefficiencies, so that the problem does not pop up in the first place.

So, the use of dynamic allocation in the code below is, with modern C++, very *artifical* and *construed*; it does not have any practical advantage.

But with this dynamic allocation, even if for this example it is artificial and construed, proper deallocation must be guaranteed, and the general way to do that is to ***use a smart pointer*** such as `std::unique_ptr`:

```
#include <iostream>         // std::cout, std::endl
#include <memory>           // std::unique_ptr, std::default_delete
#include <string>           // std::string, std::to_string

namespace foo {
    using namespace std;

    class MyObject
    {
    friend struct default_delete<MyObject>;
    private:
        string      description_;

    protected:
        virtual ~MyObject() {}  // Restrics class to dynamic allocation only.

    public:
        typedef unique_ptr<MyObject> Ptr;

        string description() const { return description_; }

        MyObject( int const x, int const y )
            : description_( "(" + to_string( x + 0LL ) + ", " + to_string( y + 0LL ) + ")" )
        {}
    };

    ostream& operator<<( ostream& stream, MyObject const& obj )
    {
        return stream << obj.description();
    }

    int gcd( int a, int b )
    {
        return (b == 0? a : gcd( b, a % b ));
    }

    MyObject::Ptr reduce( int const a, int const b )
    {
        int const gcd_ab = gcd( a, b );
        return MyObject::Ptr( new MyObject( a/gcd_ab, b/gcd_ab ) );
    }
}  // namespace foo

int main()
{
    using namespace foo;
    
    int const   a = 42;
    int const   b = 36;

    MyObject::Ptr const pData( new MyObject( a, b ) );
    MyObject::Ptr const pResult( reduce( a, b ) );

    cout << *pData << " -> " << *pResult << endl;
}
```

Note the `protected` destructor and the `friend` declaration of the code that calls the destructor. The `protected` destructor ensures that no static or automatic instances can be created, that only dynamic allocation can be used (e.g., one might impose this restriction just to make it easier to implement the class and to ensure to no automatic object is linked to in a dynamic data structure). The `friend` declaration makes the `protected` destructor accessible to the standard library’s object destruction function  –  which, however, is unfortunately only used by `unique_ptr`.

I’m mentioning and exemplifying this because you have a factory function, which is sometimes used to restrict a class to dynamic allocation (especially by folks coming from Java). A factory function is ungood for this purpose, because with *n* constructors you need *n* factory functions. In contrast, with the `protected` destructor you only need a common deleter function, and as shown above, that’s provided by the standard library.

So, upshot, generally the answer to the question “How do I correctly allocate memory so there are no leaks” is to ***delegate deallocation responsibility to the language or the standard library***, or to other library components. First and foremost this means using automatic storage (local variables) and value returns. But when there is a need, it also includes using standard library collection classes such as `std::vector` and `std::map`. Only if those do not provide the desired functionality, consider dynamic allocation. And then delegate the deallocation responsibility to smart pointers such as `std::unique_ptr` and `std::shared_ptr`.

Answer (score 2):

Usually you would return a `std::unique_ptr<MyObject>`, and do something like:

```
return std::unique_ptr<MyObject>(Manager::Create(i, j), &Manager::Free);
```

Or are you trying to write `Manager::Create` yourself?  If so:

```
std::unique_ptr<MyObject> Manager::Create(int i, int j)
{
    return std::unique_ptr<MyObject>(new MyObject(i, j)); // default deleter is appropriate
}
```

Comment: I can't control what is coming in, I have to return it without any other libraries.

Comment: @James: Well this would be in the standard library.  Whether you like it or not you are in fact using libraries that you did not write.  BOOST also has a scoped pointer type.